# removing the key from a key value pair of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, key

Let's say I have this Array of objects:

```
[300: {a:"some", b:"value"}, 301: {a: "another", b: "val"} ...]
```

I have that kind of object and I am iterating using recursive function, and there's no way I will change my counter to start at 300, I always start at 0.

I am thinking of a solution, to remove the keys from the agrray so that I will have an array like so:

```
[{a:"some", b:"value"}, {a: "another", b: "val"} ...]
```

How do I do that in javascript? Also, if there is another way that would be much faster than creatng a function that will remove keys, it will be much better.

Comment: You know that what you have is just an Array, with attributes `300`, `301`, etc, right?

Comment: ahh, yes, it'll be much better to use the word Array, thank you

Comment: Actually your expected output is an Array of objects, but your actual Array has no elements at all.

Comment: I think you misunderstand, @JoeySalacHipolito. That first thing is an object with a bunch of key/values, not an array. You've just used the wrong syntax. It should be `{ 300: {}... }`. Try plugging that into the console and you'll get a syntax error.

Comment: uhmm, but still I used that format in looping, so I can do: `somefunction(data[counter].a, data[counter].b)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you a syntax error (SyntaxError: missing ] after element list):

```
var data = [300: {a:"some", b:"value"}, 301: {a: "another", b: "val"}];
```

You mean this:

```
var data = {300: {a:"some", b:"value"}, 301: {a: "another", b: "val"}};
```

And to convert that into an array, loop over the object and push each value into a new array:

```
var arr = [];
for (var k in data) {
  arr.push(data[k]);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mw5YF/)

Comment: actually when I looked at the retured object of my code, yeah, it's not in the `[]`, it's in `{}`, dunno why I thought it was in `[]`

Answer (score 1):

There is a point here that should be clarified. When you have a Array object which its values starts from 300 as its indexes, it means you have 300 indexes with `undefined` values, but if it  is just an `Array-like` object it could be totally different.

Let's say this is not an Array-like and is an actual `Array`, so you have to filter it so that all the `undefined` values get removed from your array, so your array should be like:

```
var arr = [/*0*/undefined, ..,/*299*/undefined, /*300*/{a:"some", b:"value"}, /*301*/ {a: "another", b: "val"} ...]
var result = arr.filter(function(value,index){
    return (value !== undefined);
});
```

but what you have mentioned in your question, is more likely a javascript object, so to do what you want you can do:

```
var myObj = {300: {a:"some", b:"value"}, 301: {a: "another", b: "val"} };
var result = {};
for(var key in obj){
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        result.push(obj[key]);
    }
}
```

in this for loop `hasOwnProperty` function helps you make sure if it is one of the actual object values, and not other possible keys from the object's prototype chain.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant that the initial structure of array is this:

```
var data = [{300: {a:"some", b:"value"}}, {301: {a: "another", b: "val"}}];
```

then this should work (result array):

```
var result = [];
var data = [{300: {a:"some", b:"value"}}, {301: {a: "another", b: "val"}}];
for(var i =0; i < data.length; i++){
    for(var key in data[i]) {
        if(data[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            result.push(data[i][key]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```